# C# How to call different functions with strings of its names?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm implementing a dialogue system for a game. I'm using xml for the data cause I want the dialogues to be editable/added from outside and I have a programming problem that I never faced before.

Let's say I have this XML element:

```
<Action character="MC" name="giveItem" item="Potion" quantity="2"/>
```

It should tell the system that it have to give the MC 2 potions. In a example, like this:

```
MainCharacter.Inventory.giveItem("Potion",2)
```

My question is: How can I call `giveItem()` and the other functions I'll probably use in my game with the string of it name that came from the 'name' attribute?? So far I've seen(without implementing) reflection as a posibillity and a dictionary of strings as key and delegates as value.

I want to know is there is a better known way before starting to code that part of the system. I'm using Unity if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Will all methods have the same parameters/signature?  For example: `function (string, int)`

Comment: @BlackFrog No, they will have different parameters. But I could use strings and inside the method cast them to what I need. Now, the number of parameters, that will be different for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Unity, another way to do that would be calling the GameObject.SendMessage method.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html

The arguments are passed as an object, so you would have to find a way to pass your arguments on a container and the function that receives it would have to know how to "uncompact" them, but I'm guessing a Dictionary that translates from strings to object would be ok for arguments.

The problem with using delegates is that they would have to be the same type (take the same number and types of arguments), but you could use delegates that all take a Dictionary as stated above.

Another way to do it would be to implement the Command design pattern, that encapsulates behaviour inside an object:
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html

Essentially, while reading the XML, you would create a GiveItemCommand object that is of a subclass of Command. You would then execute the object when the action needs to be applied.

Comment: I'll take a look on SendMessage, but I wanted to avoid MonoBehaviour for the system. The only script that extends from it is the one that displays the dialog.

Comment: @Mbastias You could still use delegates that take as an argument an xml element and just do with it something. But if you want to have greater abstraction, I think reflection is the way to go. That's the most decoupled way you can do it. Just seems like overkill, that's all.

If you want to decouple behaviour, you could try to implement the Command pattern, which is essentially creating an object that know how to apply the action.http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html

Comment: @Mbastias So, when you read the xml, what you do is create a command subclass object that knows what it has to do.

Comment: Didn't see the edit on your answer, I'll leave the question unanswered one day more in case that someone has another way or opinion, if not I'll mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Thanks ^^ As long as it helped you.